# SSRS - Dropdowns Changed Based on Previous Selection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create an SSRS report based off reports that used to run off ASPX pages.

In the old ASPX reports, there were two dropdowns.

One dropdown had the following:
Day
Month
Year

If the user selected "Day", then a calendar was shown and they could select a date from the calendar.  If "Month" was selected, then a dropdown was shown with only the months available in the database.  If "Year" was selected, then a dropdown was shown with only the years available in the database.

How would I be able to accomplish this same in the SSRS Reports?

Comment: You can't show/hide parameters dynamically in SSRS. So you will need to create all of your potential parameters and allow nulls or blanks. Then handle that in your query depending on the `Day Month Year` selection.

Comment: Not sure if this would work in your case, but you could try searching on "ssrs cascading parameters example"

Comment: Thank you for the response, but just so I understand.....  I would need to show all the parameters, so I would need a "Day" / "Month" / "Year" and they pick the one they want?  The other two are shown but might be NULL?

Comment: You can have a dropdown for the first parameter `Day Month Year` list. Then have a DateTime parameter and allow null. A Month dropdown list allow blank. Then a Year dropdown list allow blank (this will get populated by a query to select all of the Years in your data).

Comment: Not sure they will work, as it would be a different parameter for each item selected.  Added to that, I am supposed to call a different stored procedure based on the selection of the "Day" parameter.  So if they select "day", I call one stored procedure and "month" a different one and "year" a different one

Comment: @WEI_DBA:  I understand what you are saying, but they want to hide the parameters based on the selection of the first parameter.  Not show them with NULL values.  This will prevent the user from selecting "bad" values if we can hide them

Comment: As I said before, you can't dynamically show/hide parameters in SSRS.

Comment: Actually, I think you can do this starting with SSRS 2016.   Haven't verified, but I know it introduces a new "dynamic parameters" feature.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.  We are using 2013 I believe but I know definately not 2016.  Appreciate all the help guys